# clone mercurial project throws abort

Tags: python, mercurial

Im trying to clone a repository hosted on atlasian (Mercurial). It throws

```
     abort: certificate checking requires Python 2.6
```

I have other repository on the server which I can perform pull, merge other operations.

The python version of my server is 2.4
If python version is an issue, then why I can perform pull,push and other operations on other repository?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or Git. Please don't tag-spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that using Python 2.6 allows you to do better certificate verification when accessing remote repositories over SSL.  I imagine this is a setting on the specific repository/server over at Atlassian.

You can tell Mercurial to do an "insecure" clone/push/pull.  This will not attempt to verify the server certificate, and so will not require Python 2.6:

```
hg clone --insecure <repository>
```

I confess to not really playing about with certificates, but you can have a look at the [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/)/[CACertificates](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates) wiki page for some information on how you may be able to fix.  Basically you can configure your Mercurial installation to reference the certificates provided.